# way to copy a class that is a Handle Class?

Tags: class, matlab, copy, handle

I have a class that is by handle, and I want to copy it by value and store it somewhere.  However, if I change anything in the class, it also changes the copy of it.

Here is an example of my class I want to copy:

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties
        data;
    end
    methods
        function M = MyClass()
           M.data=5; 
        end
    end      
end
```

Here is a test class to test changes:

```
classdef Test < handle  
    properties 
        store 
    end 
    methods 
         function N = Test(M) 
             N.store = M; 
         end 
    end 
end
```

Now, we create an instance of MyClass and store it in Test:

```
>> m=MyClass
m =
  MyClass handle
  Properties:
    data: 5
  Methods, Events, Superclasses

>> a=Test(m)
a = 
  Test handle
  Properties:
    store: [1x1 MyClass]
  Methods, Events, Superclasses

>> a.store
ans =
  MyClass handle
  Properties:
    data: 5
  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

Finally, if I change the value of 'data' in 'm' I do NOT want it to change the value in store, however it seems like MyClass is stored in 'store' by reference:

```
>> m.data=3;
>> a.store
ans = 
  MyClass handle
  Properties:
    data: 3
  Methods, Events, Superclasses

>> a.store.data
ans =
     3
```

Is it possible to copy a "handle" class?  Or do I need to change my class to make by value for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it copyable by deriving from [matlab.mixin.CopyableClass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html), see the link for details.

Comment: nice! this is exactly what I needed :)